# Add element and key to array php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add an element to array, but I get a weird output. The code is the following:

```
$getalltokens = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Tables WHERE available = '$comp'");
    while ($row = $getalltokens->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $fid = $row['FID'];
        $tok = $row['token'];
        $sql = $db->query("SELECT Firstname,Lastname FROM Users WHERE Token = '$tok'");
        $rez = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $names[] = $rez;
        $fidzy = array(
            'FID' => $fid
        );
        array_push($names, $fidzy);
    }
    $getalltokens = $db->query("SELECT FID FROM Tables WHERE available = '$comp'");
    $tokenz = $getalltokens->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($names);
```

And the output I get is:

```
[{"Firstname":"Test","Lastname":"Test"},{"FID":"5"},
{"Firstname":"Test2","Lastname":"Test2"},{"FID":"4"}]
```

While what I need is the FID to be inside the `$names` array, so it would be more like:

```
[{"Firstname":"Test","Lastname":"Test","FID":"5"}]
```

Comment: You don't need `$fidzy` there. Just do `$names['FID'] = $fid;` and get rid of `array_push()`.

Comment: @Ulver, you did same mistake like me. $names is array of arrays.

Comment: @ShamilYakupov Gotcha! Agreed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$rez['FID'] = $fid; /* Added */
$names[] = $rez;
/* $fidzy and array_push removed */
```

Comment: The result of that is the following: `{"0":{"Firstname":"Vukasin","Lastname":"Vulovic"},"FID":"9"}` Do you think if I change the query to grab all the data at once, it would help? I'm gonna try that now

Comment: No worries, however, the new snippet results in the following: 

`Notice: Undefined variable: names in /home/user/domain/api/getusers.php on line 46
null`

Line 46 is the `echo json_encode($names);` If I understood correctly, you're trying to add key and value to `$rez` which isn't an array? Since I'm doing the while for every token separately?

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` returning an array, so $rez is an array. Did you declare your `$names` before `while`? Also, I dont know what are you trying to do, but better to make it in one query like `SELECT t.*, u.Firstname, u.Lastname FROM Tables as t, Users as u WHERE u.Token = t.token AND t.available = '$comp'`.

Comment: I didn't delcare, that's what I'm looking to do but I'm pretty stuck here: 
`$sql = $db->query("SELECT Users.Firstname,Users.Lastname FROM Users LEFT JOIN Tables.FID ON Users.Token = Tables.token WHERE Users.Token = '$tok'");` not the best left joiner I'll admit

Answer (score 1):

You can use instead of `array_push()` like

```
$arrayname[indexname] = $value;
```

if you use `array_push()`

```
<?php
$array[] = $var;
?>
```

> ```
> Note: If you use `array_push()` to add one element to the array it's
> ```
>
> better to use`$array[] =` because in that way there is no overhead of
>   calling a function.
>
> ```
> Note: `array_push()` will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the `$var[]` behavior where a new array
> ```
>
> is created.

Reference [Array push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: This is true, however, in this very specific case, a different solution is the best. Your suggestion does give the desired output, but changes formating or adds the FID without `FID:1`, just adds `1`. I'll post the answer in a second

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the specific problem at hand is selecting all the necessary data in a single query, removing the need to add elements to any array. This is done in the following fashion:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT
Users.Firstname,Users.Lastname,Tables.FID
FROM Users,Tables 
WHERE Users.Token = Tables.token");
$rez = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rez);
```